# sonar configuration for mysql failing

Tags: php, mysql, continuous-integration, jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to run sonar-runner against our repo for the first time...

I have:

1. Installed Sonar 3.2 and installed in /opt/sonar
2. Installed and configured the sonar-runner in /opt/sonar-runner-2.0/
3. Installed the PHP extension plugin and put into /opt/sonar/extensions/plugins/sonar-php-plugin-1.1.jar

My sonar.properties file has these properties:

```
   sonar.jdbc.username:                       sonar
   sonar.jdbc.password:                       sonar
   sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
   sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Eventhough the user/password are set to sonar/sonar, sonar-runner is still attempting to connect as root@localhost... See trace below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.initDatasource(DefaultDatabase.java:117)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:62)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 30 more
```

I have restarted the sonar server after making changes to the config...

Is it possible to use an empty/blank password? If I comment out `sonar.jdbc.password`, then sonar GUI will throw a 500 status code. If I leave `sonar.jdbc.password` empty/blank, then it still tries connecting with a password: `'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`!!

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stacktrace details the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Doesn't look like the configuration matches your error. Did you try configuration Sonar to use the user root?

I suspect your issue has to do with mySQL user access. Have you tried connecting to the database as the "sonar" user?

## Update

The [Sonar runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Sonar+Runner) does not use the same configuration file as the Sonar server. Look for a file in the following location:

```
$SONAR_RUNNER_HOME/conf/sonar-runner.properties
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, i've had another look at it this morning with a fresh pair of eyes... I have re-added a new user to the DB: `CREATE USER 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';` and then `GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';` I then tested this worked from the cli: `mysql -u sonar -h localhost -p sonar`. All is good. I update entries in `/opt/sonar/conf/sonar.properties` to use the sonar user and sonar password. Restart the sonar server. I can see the sonar GUI through the web address. However, the sonar-runner is still trying to connect to mysql as `root@localhost`?

Comment: Thankyou Mark. I didn't realise the sonar-runner had a separate credential configuration. Another solution for the Sonar plugin in Jenkins is to put the user/password configuration in the `Project Properties` section. This will override anything in the Sonar installation configuration itself. Cheers

Comment: I had a similar problem, but for me changing Sonar Runner configuration didn't help, had to add MySQL related bits to Sonar's own `sonar.properties`.

Comment: @dain Well naturally. Sonar out of the box talks to an embedded H2 database. You need to configure the server to talk to your MySQL backend. I suppose what's confusing is that the Sonar client does all the real work (Thick client) within the build process. Results are afterwards uploaded directly into the back-end database, by-passing the Sonar REST API (The API's main purpose is to configure the various tools that run within the build process).

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing first, thanks for the clarification!